# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol when some files have been added from existing project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, linker-errors

I have copied some of the files from my existing project into new  project. Everything works fine but I have started getting
 `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class MessagingInterface message" (?message@@3VMessagingInterface@@A)`

The file which throws above error has  `extern MessagingInterface message ;` declared in .cpp file. I have two other files MessagingInterface.h and .cpp  which declares and defines function for MessagingInterface class.
The interesting thing to note is both these projects are build under vs2010 but the new one has some qt functions in it so obviously I am building with qt plugin and moc files etc
I have added files in the build using Cmake.
Any tiny help will be fruitful for me..

MessageInterface.h

```
//#include <afxmt.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QString>

#include "sms_list.h"

class sms_list;


/* Macro to output the current position in the code
 */
#define CODE_CHECKPOINT message( MessageType::CODE ) \
    << __FILE__ << ", line " << __LINE__ << std::endl

/** Centralised messaging interface for printing messages to the display and to
  * disk
  */
class MessagingInterface  
{
public:
    /** Which messages to write to which stream
      */
    struct Config
    {
        std::ostream*       os;
        MessageType::Enum   types[ MessageType::NUMBER_OF_MESSAGE_TYPES ];
    };

    /** Allows more than one stream to be written to at the same time
      */
    class Proxy
    {
        friend class MessagingInterface;

    public:
        ~Proxy();
        std::ostream& getStream( void ) const;

    private:
        Proxy( MessagingInterface* ptr );
        Proxy( const Proxy& other ) {}

        MessagingInterface* parent_;
    };

    friend class Proxy;

    MessagingInterface( const Config* cstart, const Config* cend ); 

    /** Give responsibility to write to the streams to a proxy that will do the
      * work for the messaging class
      */
    Proxy operator() ( const MessageType::Enum type );
    template<typename Type>
 void operator ()( const Type& value )
 {
    QMutex mutex;
    mutex.lock();
           //CSingleLock        lock( &criticalSection_, true );

    for( const Config* iter = start_; iter != end_; ++iter )
        *(iter->os) << value;
}

    /** Outputs the value straight to all the streams
      */
    template<typename Type>
    void operator ()( const Type& value )
    {
        QMutex mutex;
        mutex.lock();
  //CSingleLock lock( &criticalSection_, true );

        for( const Config* iter = start_; iter != end_; ++iter )
            *(iter->os) << value;
    }


    void timestamp( void );

    /** Timestamps the specified stream
      */
    void timestamp( std::ostream& os );

private:
    /** Outputs the message and the type
      */
    void output( const MessageType::Enum type, QString str ) const;

    sms_list*               sms_list_;

    std::stringstream           ss_;
    MessageType::Enum           type_;

    const Config*               start_;
    const Config*               end_;

    //mutable CCriticalSection  criticalSection_;
      mutable QMutex mutex_;
};

/** Outputs a CString as text instead of as a pointer
  */
inline std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& os, const QString& str )
{
 os << ( str ).toStdString();
    return os;
}

/** Outputs the value to the proxy stream then returns a reference to the
  * stream so other items can be sent to it
  */
template<typename Type>
std::ostream& operator <<( MessagingInterface::Proxy& proxy, const Type& value )
{
    //somecode
 }
```

// MessageInterface.cpp

```
    #include "MessagingInterface.h"
#include "SMS_list.h"
#include "lib_utils/Exception.h"
#include <boost/function.hpp>


#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <QString>
#include <QTime>
#include <qvariant.h>
#include <QDateTime>

#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[]=__FILE__;
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

using namespace MessageType;
using namespace std;
using namespace platform;

namespace
{

 bla bla .. some functions


}

MessagingInterface::MessagingInterface( const Config* cstart, const Config* cend )
: message_list_( NULL ), start_( cstart ), end_( cend )
{
    ss_.setf( ios::boolalpha );
}

/** Give responsibility to write to the streams to a proxy that will do the
  * work for the messaging class
  */
MessagingInterface::Proxy MessagingInterface::operator() ( const MessageType::Enum type )
{
    type_ = type;
    return this;
}
// some other functions
```

Calling.cpp

```
    #some other files
#include "MessagingInterface.h"
#include "calling.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG
#undef THIS_FILE
static char THIS_FILE[]=__FILE__;
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif

extern MessagingInterface message;
// some other functions

//calling.h
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "MessagingInterface.h"


//extern MessagingInterface message; // commented out as declared in cpp file. But I have tried uncommenting here n commenting on cpp and vice versa
```

HI Guys , if i just use `extern MessageInterface message` in calling.cpp it compiles fine but if i use even one function or macro from MessageInterface it throws linker error. For example I have used `CODE_CHECKPOINT` in calling.cpp and it start throwing linker error .. IM completely clueless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved ..

extern MessagingInterface message  was throwing error in calling .cpp  as Message was not defined . Since I have copy and paste few files from existinmg project into new project , I failed to define message  . After defining it   in some other files it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
extern MessagingInterface message ;
```

its a declaration. It should be included in a header file. Apart from this you should also define this variable in some module. It is being done by either removing keyword extern or by keeping this keyword but initializing this variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But shouldn I only need to declare it the calling file.cpp because after all its teh cpp fiel which gets into compilation.  Anyways , I ahve added it the calling.h file as well and still it throws error.

Comment: Also interesting to note when i compile files individually they all compiled without any errors.

Comment: Did you remove keyword extern in the variable definition in the cpp file?

Comment: you mean in teh calling cpp ? I have tried both like reoving extern from cpp file as well as leaving it there , but nothing happens

Comment: its interesting because other project is working fine and it is infact using all these files. what I did is copy and paste in th my new prj directory and  add those file name in Cmake.txt for building

Comment: I will post my code in  a min  to give you guys a clear picture

Comment: HI  Guys ,  if i just use extern MessageInterface message  in calling.cpp it compiles fine but if i use even one faction or macro from MessageInterface it thows linker error. For example I have used CODE_CHECKPOINT in calling.cpp and it start thorwing linker error